# Remove specific sign when filtering in Django

Tags: django, database-cursor

I have this query in my `views.py`

```
    cardId = request.POST.get('id')
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
         cursor.execute("SELECT category1_id FROM app_card_tbl WHERE id =%s", [cardId])
         row = cursor.fetchone()
        
         cursor.execute("SELECT name FROM app_category1_tbl WHERE id =%s",[row])
         tab1 = cursor.fetchone()

         print(tab1)
```

**And the output of this when print is**

```
('thisisname',)
```

**All i want is the output should looks like below** must remove the `(',) sign it is possible?

```
thisisname
```

Comment: if it is a tuple and you are interested in first value, can you use index?  Like tab1[0]

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because each record is put in a tuple, even if it contains a single column. You can print the first item with:

```
print(tab1[0])
```

or you can unwrap it when fetching the object:

```
tab1, = cursor.fetchone()
print(tab1)
```